# Date time format in php - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I have this kind of error, and wondering if there's anyway I can fix this

```
  public function someFunction(int $referral_id)
    {
        $data = DB::table('someTables')
            ->where('referral_id', $referral_id)
            ->first();

        return $data ? (object) [
            'planId' => $data->plan_id ?? '',
            'comment' => $data->comment ?? '',
            'facilitator' => $data->facilitator ?? '',
            'time' => $data->started_at->format('H:i:s') ?? '',
        ] : (object) [];
    }

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on string
```

that is the error message returning,

My database is saving date and time on a single column but I like them to be separated, is it possible?

Thanks Lads

Comment: By default database dates are read as strings. You need to [add a date cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to the `started_at` field if you're using eloquent or cast it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you're using it without a Model and so the data will be returned in it's raw format, in this case a string.

Using PHP `date` and `strtotime` should give you the time from the ISO8601 string

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime($data->started_at));
```

Comment: Thank you, the code you shared fits like a glove.. youre awesome,

I presume that the date goes similar as well.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: I tried this on the date but it gives me a warning and it wont reflect on the UI
 The specified value "2021-09-01" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "HH:mm", "HH:mm:ss" or "HH:mm:ss.SSS" where HH is 00-23, mm is 00-59, ss is 00-59, and SSS is 000-999.

Comment: So if the string is `2021-09-01` that means your database must be a "DATE" column not a "DATETIME" you're not storing the time only the date

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that and investigate, and thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction.